# Creating Dataframe column using apply() in Python

Tags: python

Say you have a Table T with Columns A and B with numerical values.  I want to create a new column C that gives me the ratio of A/B.  I know the easy way to do this.

```
T['C']=T['A']/T['B']
```

But I want to try using the apply() function to a new copy of Table T.  I have the following function below to execute this for any tables.

```
def ratio(T):
    X=T.copy()
    def ratio(a,b):
        return a/b
    X['C']=X['C'].apply(ratio,'A','B')
    return X
```

I get the KeyError: 'C' error.  How do I properly get 'C' to exist in order to apply it/

Answer (score 1):

You could simplify this with lambda:

```
X = T.copy()

X['C'] = T.apply(lambda row: row.A/row.B, axis=1)
```